# Is there a way to deploy java web start application in sandbox without the scary warning?

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start

My java webstart runs in sandbox, it doesn't access local files, arbitrary network files, sound recorders, camera, it only needs limited functionalities such as computation, mouse events, etc.  But still, when the user click the jnlp file, a window pops up asking whether the user wanted to run this application without signature, and says there is risk.

I thougt if my java web start is in sandbox, there is no need to remind the user that there is risk?  My jnlp file has no  tags so I didn't ask for all permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a signed application in a restricted environment can exploit bugs; the warning should not be defeated. Instead, embrace the security features discussed in [*Security and Code Signing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html#security). In particular,

- Don't request unnecessary permissions.
- Do sign your JAR; even a self-signed certificate can detect tampering.

Comment: It does seem in that case, we may as well deploy everything as `<all-permissions>`.  At least that way we avoid things like `Java Applet Window` warnings & prompts for use of the JNLP API.  The last remaining advantage of deploying with restricted permissions would be to suggest a prompt for desktop integration or file associations.

Comment: Good point. One some hosts, I intentionally decline to "Always trust..." my own certificate as a reminder to check the fingerprint.

Comment: *"I intentionally decline to "Always trust..." my own certificate"*  Same here, for the same reasons.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  I might just request all-permission as I am already using the jnlp api and thinking hard how to avoid annoy users too much.